# phpUnit: Stop on Notice

Tags: php, phpunit

how can I make phpUnit to stop on any notices like this:

```
Notice: Undefined property: _global::$tra in 
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sakkadentrainer/classes/_global.php on line 1684
✔ Check if trainer chooser popup works [569.58 ms]
```

This Test passed, even-though I got some errors.

In the phpUnit Doc I cant find something like

```
--stop-on-error
```

https://phpunit.de/manual/6.5/en/textui.html

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try `--stop-on-warning`?

Comment: Yes, I did. It also does not stop the test...

Comment: Anyone? Still looking for an answer!

Answer (score 0):

The phpUnit option `beStrictAboutOutputDuringTests="true" (--disallow-test-output`) helps. With that the test still passes, but I get a "risky" test output.